# How to make ArgoCD Non-HA to HA setup?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, argocd

I have currently implemented ArgoCD for my K8's deployment. I installed it as a **Non-HA** setup. Moving forward, the number of application in ArgoCD will get increased. I prefer to go with **HA** setup now.

Is there a proper way to convert it from Non-HA to HA without affecting any Applications.

**Note**: I tried to upgrade by executing the [HA YAML](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/v2.0.0/manifests/ha/install.yaml) file directly using `kubectl` command in my existing Non-HA cluster. Even though it worked, but not sure if that's the right way.
`kubectl apply -n argocd -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/v2.0.0/manifests/ha/install.yaml`

Comment: I'm not aware of any reason that shouldn't work. Definitely upgrade to a newer version asap though, 2.0 is getting kinda old.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Going to perform the same with 2.1 --> 2.3 Argo Non-HA to HA upgrade.
Haven't found anything in the docs as well.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31748195)